# Change CSS class by Javascript when default class is set by ID

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV that has CSS applied to it in an external stylesheet by ID, such as:

```
<div id="myFavoriteDIVever">Stuff</div>

#myFavoriteDIVever {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, in a Javascript function, I set the following class to that same DIV:

```
document.getElementById('myFavoriteDIVever').className = 'superCoolClass';

.superCoolClass {
    display: block;
}
```

For some reason, when I do it this way, the DIV is not set to display as block. It remains not displayed in the DOM. But if I change it so the DIV has a default CSS class applied to it that sets display: none; then I set a different CSS class to it with Javascript later that sets display: block; it works as expected and displays the DIV as a block element.

Why would the CSS class override the ID CSS? So, when I apply a new className it should override the #element settings. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ascending order of specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Universal
> - selectors Type
> - selectors Class
> - selectors Attributes
> - selectors Pseudo-classes
> - ID selectors
> - Inline style

You can overwrite it using inline-styling

```js
document.getElementById('myFavoriteDIVever').style.display = 'block';
```

```css
#myFavoriteDIVever {
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red
}
```

```html
<div id="myFavoriteDIVever" class="myFavoriteDIVever">Stuff</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I wasn't aware of the priorities. I'm trying to avoid using inline styles in my Javascript so it's more easily editable.

Comment: I picked your answer because you provided very useful documentation around specificity. I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ids have a higher priority so adding a class will not have any effect. Your best shot is:

```
<div id="myFavoriteDIVever" class="myFavoriteDIVever">Stuff</div>

.myFavoriteDIVever {
    display: none;
}
document.getElementById('myFavoriteDIVever').className = 'superCoolClass';
```

Comment: The default class is unnecessary. Chaining ID and class in CSS (e.g. #myFavoriteDIVever.superCoolClass { ... } ) will do it.

Comment: So, @SebastianHomeier, I'd do: #myFavoriteDIVever.hide and #myFavoriteDIVever.show . In Javascript, to change it to "show", would I just do document.getElementById('myFavoriteDIVever').className = 'show'? Does that effectively do it?

Comment: Disregard. I tried it and it worked. Thank you so much! That's a clean, flexible solution.

Comment: Basically, yes. You won't need the `.hide` class since your ID selector already has `display: none;`. I just posted a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with your javascript, its with the CSS. There is a concept called specificity. The idea is that each CSS entry has some specificity value (1000, 100, 10, 1). The style that will be applied is the one that is the most "specific". An ID selector = 100. A class selector = 10. The id will win. Try changing the css for the class from

> `.superCoolClass {
>       display: block;
>   }`

to

> `#myFavoriteDIVever.superCoolClass {
>       display: block;
>   }`

Answer (score 0):

This should do fine:

HTML:

```
<div id="myFavoriteDIVever">Stuff</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myFavoriteDIVever {
    display: none;
}

#myFavoriteDIVever.show {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('myFavoriteDIVever').className = 'show';
```